# Google AutoML Object detection data split error

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, google-cloud-automl

I have images dataset which I am trying to run Object detection using Google's AutoML object detection.

I manually split the data into train, test and validate.

However, when I upload the csv into the dataset, I am getting the following Errors few times:
"Error: Example is deduped with example id: 2289134970725637758."

[image: Error message screenshot]

[image: CSV - chickennuggets]

[image: Number of splits on Vision AutoML after csv upload]

I noticed it's not reading the images I set to VALIDATION on a certain label (chickennuggets).
Also, the numbers per split are not matching the number of images per split on my csv.

I need the model to read and assign images to the SET (train, test or validate) I put it as in the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that some of your examples are duplicated.

I suggest that you check your CSV for duplicate examples (image + bounding box) or more specifically, check your VALIDATION examples for that particular label to be sure you didn't duplicate examples from the other sets.

And if you didn't already, you should also go through the [CSV formatting guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/csv-format), just in case.

In the eventuality that you wouldn't find any duplicates, then I recommend you to create an [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).